# question about series, geometric sum

Tags: power-series

the questions is:

Determine the series:

a) express 1/x in terms of (x+1)^k

guidance: use t=x+1 and geometric sum and term derivative

Have never really seen these types of questions before and couldnt find anything  in my mathbook

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please check this-MathJax(https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also this-How to ask a good question(https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: hint: what is the sum of a geometric series $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n$ ? when $|x|<1$ and $n\to\infty$ what is the limit ?

Comment: If I saw that question, I might let $y=1+x$ and then try to express $-\frac{1}{1-y}$ in terms of $y^k$ within its radius of convergence before translating back to $x$

Comment: Thanks Henry, that helped alot :)